# Can I use a docker volume with S3FS?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, fuse, s3fs

I would like to have a shared directory between my containers: `ftp` and `s3fs`. Todo so, I have created a volume in my docker-compose file called `s3`.

If I stop `s3fs` from running in my `s3fs` container, then I can create files in the `ftp` container and they will show up in side `s3fs` under `/home/files`.

However, when running `s3fs` the directory `/home/files` remains empty whilst I create files in the `ftp`.

This is what my /proc/mounts file looks like:

```
/dev/sda2 /home/files ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
s3fs /home/files fuse.s3fs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
```

I belive fuse maybe overriding my docker volume, has anyone encountered this problem before?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  ftp:
    image: app/proftpd:latest
    volumes:
      - s3:/home/files
    ports:
      - 2222:2222

  s3fs:
    image: app/s3fs:latest
    command: start
    env_file:
      - s3fs/aws.env
    volumes:
      - s3:/home/files
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    devices:
      - "/dev/fuse"
    environment:
      ENVIRONMENT: "dev"

volumes:
  s3:
```

s3fs - Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y \
            software-properties-common
RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y \
            automake \
            autotools-dev \
            fuse \
            g++ \
            git \
            libcurl4-openssl-dev \
            libfuse-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            libxml2-dev \
            make \
            pkg-config \
            curl

RUN curl -L https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/archive/v1.84.tar.gz | tar zxv -C /usr/src
RUN cd /usr/src/s3fs-fuse-1.84 && ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl && make && make install

COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/s3fs/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN mkdir -p /home/files

WORKDIR /opt/s3fs/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

s3fs - entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $1 in

start)
    echo "Starting S3Fs: "
    s3fs mybucket /home/files -o allow_other,nonempty -d -d
;;

esac
```

ftp - Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssh-server \
    proftpd-basic \
    proftpd-mod-mysql

COPY proftpd.conf /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
COPY sftp.conf /etc/proftpd/conf.d/sftp.conf
COPY setup.sh /etc/proftpd/setup.sh

RUN chmod 500 /etc/proftpd/setup.sh && /etc/proftpd/setup.sh

EXPOSE 2222

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/etc/proftpd/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope, I eventually gave up trying to use a volume and ended up just combining my two docker images. s3fs was then able to pick up files. I'm not enterally sure why using a volume does not work, I think fuse maybe overrides it.

Comment: Thanks @Freid001, I think I will end up doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount s3 in your docker container in next way

1.Add to `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apt-get install -y fuse s3fs
RUN mkdir /root/.aws
RUN touch /root/.aws/.passwd-s3fs && chmod 600 /root/.aws/.passwd-s3fs
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod 700 entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT entrypoint.sh
```

2.Create entrypoint.sh with next script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$AWS_CREDS" > /root/.aws/.passwd-s3fs
echo "$BUCKET_NAME /srv/files fuse.s3fs _netdev,allow_other,passwd_file=/root/.aws/.passwd-s3fs 0 0" > /etc/fstab
mount -a
<your old CMD or ENTRYPOINT>
```

3.In docker-compose.yml add next

```
<your-container-name>:
   image: ...
   build: ...
   environment:
      - AWS_ID="AKI..."
      - AWS_KEY="omIE..."
      - AWS_CREDS=AKI...:2uMZ...
      - BUCKET_NAME=<YOUR backed name>
   devices:
      - "/dev/fuse"
   cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
   security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
```